# Is the terminal that you get when typing Ctrl+Alt+F# a process?

Tags: terminal, console

I understand that when I open a terminal emulator like `xterm`, and then list the processes using `ps`, I can see `xterm` running as a process.

But when I type Ctrl+Alt+F#, I get a "full screen terminal", is this "full screen terminal" also a process? or is it a UI provided by the kernel without being an actual process?

Comment: no - that doesn't answer this question.

Comment: @ThomasDickey I have to second (fourth) jasonwryan here. “The console appears to the operating system as a (kernel-implemented) tty” does answer this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unlike regular terminal emulators, this full screen terminal is not handled by a userland process but, as you guessed, provided by the kernel.

See [Virtual console](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_console)

Answer (score 0):

If I login to console 1 and type sleep 10000, and then do a process list with:

```
ps -AHl | grep -B2 sleep
```

I get

```
4 S     0  4002     1  0  80   0 - 18473 -      tty1     00:00:00   login
4 S  1000 23312  4002  0  80   0 -  8235 -      tty1     00:00:00     bash
0 S  1000 23360 23312  0  80   0 -  1452 -      tty1     00:00:00       sleep
```

The `sleep` is in `bash`, an expected.
and `bash` is in `login`
`login` has a parent id of 1, so that is all there is.

From this we see that there is a process `login`, but no process for the terminal.

Comment: This doesn't prove anything. There's no compelling reason why the process providing the terminal emulation would be a parent of the login or shell process.